# Pass array to function name collision

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, function

#### Specs

GNU bash, version 3.1.17 (No possibility of upgrade)

---

#### Premise

I've been messing around with arrays and i was wondering if there is any way to have a variable local to a function with the same name as an array outside of said function.

---

#### Example

In the below examples I will try to display the issue

Working

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(1 2 "3 4" 5)   # Make global array

myfunc()
{
    local args=("${!1}")  # Using different name for declaration
        echo ${args[@]}  # Echo new array


}
    myfunc arr[@]  # Pass array to function
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Not working

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(1 2 "3 4" 5) # Create array

myfunc()
{
    local arr=("${!1}") #Not working
        echo ${arr[@]} # Not working


}
    myfunc arr[@] # Pass array to function
```

Output

```
[Blank]
```

---

#### Reason

I want to pass multiple arrays to the function but do not want to have a possible name collision with the array being passed in and the local array name.

---

#### Tried

As you can see above i have tried adding the local function. I've scanned the bash man page and cannot seem to find anything else that could provide the behaviour i desisre

*Bash -x Results*

```
+ arr=(1 2 "3 4" 5)
+ myfunc 'arr[@]'
+ arr=("${!1}")
+ local arr
+ echo
```

---

If any more information is needed then please let me know.

Comment: Your second snippet works just fine. See http://ideone.com/9Jjb3b . Your lack of quotes around `${arr[@]}` in the function mean you are blowing up your spaces but that's a different issue.

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: @EtanReisner I didn't really mind the spaces blowing up, but it honestly doesn't work. I don't know if the version of bash would have anything to do with it(I doubt it though).

Comment: @rici GNU bash, version 3.1.17, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @EtanReisner Okay so i tried it `GNU bash, version 3.2.51` and it works, any idea why it wouldn't on `3.1.17` ?

Comment: What do you see if you add `set -x` to your script and run it in that version of bash? I'm going to guess the problem is a scope issue with how `local` and the expansion interacted in that version but I have no real idea.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried that but it didn't really return anything useful, the only thing i noticed was that it appeared it was set to local after assigning `arr=("${!1}")` but it also did that in the one that worked so I dunno. I'll post it in the question.

Comment: That's roughly the output I would expect but I still have to wonder if the problem is a scope issue on the lookup of `arr` in the expansion. That's the only thing I can think of that would cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations you've hit a bug in the 3.1 series of bash.

From the [Bash ChangeLog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) in the section relating to the bash-3.2-alpha release:

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-3.2-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-3.1-release.
>
> ...
>
> f.  Fixed two bugs with local array variable creation when shadowing a variable
>       of the same name from a previous context.

Comment: Thankyou for this answer, really appreciate you looking around for this! And now i know where to look in the future if i get stuck again :)