# Change in behaviour of declare/local from bash 4.2 to 4.3

Tags: bash

I've recently updated my system and got a new bash version. Since then I've encountered some nasty behaviour of my bash scripts, which I finally managed to track down to a new behaviour of bash's *declare* / *local* commands.

Considering the following minimal working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function printarray1 () {
  local -a arr=("${!1}")
  echo "${arr[@]}" # printing the complete array
  echo "${arr[9]}" # just to check if it is really recognized as an integer indexed array
}

function printarray2 () {
  local arr=("${!1}")
  echo "${arr[@]}" # printing the complete array
  echo "${arr[9]}" # just to check if it is really recognized as an integer indexed array
}

arr=("01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10")
echo "Declaration as indexed array:"
printarray1 arr[@]
echo "Undefined declaration:"
printarray2 arr[@]
```

On *GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*  this results in

```
Declaration as indexed array:
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
10
Undefined declaration:
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
10
```

while the newer *GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)* version returns

```
Declaration as indexed array:

Undefined declaration:
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
10
```

Note that the behaviour is the same when I use "declare" instead of "local".

I could not find anything about a change of the *declare* options in Bash 4.3. The help (*help declare*) is equal in both versions for all relevant information. I've even stumbled upon the claim that "All variables can be used as arrays without explicit definition." (see [Why are "declare -f" and "declare -a" needed in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742062/why-are-declare-f-and-declare-a-needed-in-bash-scripts)).

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Is it a new feature? Or simply a bug? Has the passing of arrays to functions been restricted? To me it's pretty scary when the bash behaviour suddenly changes from version to version.

Comment: The problem is the variable name collision. Use a different global variable and the problem goes away.

Comment: With another variable name it works indeed. But that doesn't really explain the different behaviour between Bash 4.2 and 4.3, nor _declare -a_ and _declare_. And I assumed the sense behind the _local_ keyword has been to hide variables from the local scope.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't see anything in a quick look at the notes that would explain it and I would have expected it to break completely in the newer version and not just partly. I feel like I've seen a question about this before I'll have to go looking for it in a bit.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are probably remembering [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727410/pass-array-to-function-name-collision) a few months ago although that was to do with a bug in `bash 3.1`.

Comment: @123 Almost certainly correct. Thanks. Don't have time to see if something similar applies here too at the moment though.

Comment: Looking through the change logs, i can't see anything that would suggest this behaviour is intended, so i think it is probably a bug, similar to the one in my question in my comment.

Comment: That sound reasonable, although it would be strange to have this behavior in 3.1, then fixed in 3.2 and finally re-introduced in 3.3. Although in your question, the _-a_ option is not involved.

Comment: Just came back to look at this again and I still think this has to be the same bash bug again. I'd see about talking to the bash folks about this. (I just reproduced it with bash `4.3.42(1)-release` too.) There is an entry in the bash changelog for 4.3-beta which looks like it might be vaguely related (1.d).

Comment: The bash mailing list revealed that `local -a arr=("${!1}")` will expand to `local -a arr; arr=( "${!1}" )` and then to `local -a arr; arr=( "${arr[@]}" )`. I.e. the local variable of the same name is first defined without value and hence shadows the global `arr`. Explains the behaviour, but not the exclusive occurrence with `-a` switch.